# Tautology Laws involving multiple variables

Tags: logic

I have a pretty simple question regarding basic tautological and contradiction laws.  I feel Velleman's book strives to state such them so simply it leaves out an important detail.  I'll get to that in a moment with my question.

It is said that $P ∧ (¬P ∨ P)$ (i.e., P and a tautology) is equivalent to $P$.

Likewise, it is said that $P ∨ (¬P ∨ P)$ (i.e., P or a tautology) is equivalent to the tautology itself.

When manipulating logical statements involving the former, the aforementioned set of symbols can be shortened to just $P$.  For example:
$$P ∧ (¬P ∨ P) ∨ Q ≡ P ∨ Q$$

It is easy to see why this is - if for no other reason, then the absorption laws make it quite clear.  In the case of the "P or a tautology" example, the idemptotent laws make it clear why that is true.  The contradiction laws work similarly.

So here is my question.  What if $P ∧ (¬Q ∨ Q)$ or $P ∨ (¬Q ∨ Q)$?  Is there a way to deal with these - to shorten them?  The "P and/ or" part is still true, and the "tautology" part is still true... but the tautologies involve a different variable.  Velleman's definitions were too broad as to specify what to do here.  If anything, they imply the variables do not matter.  I have a hard time believing this.  Can anybody offer any input?

Comment: It doesn't matter what variable involves, a tautology is always true. Therefor $P\land Tautology \equiv P$ and $P\lor Tautology\equiv Tautology$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can still apply the same ideas:

For $P \land (\neg Q \lor Q)$:   Since $\neg Q \lor Q$ is a tautology, we get '$P$ and a tautology', which is just $P$. So, $P \land (\neg Q \lor Q) \equiv P$

Likewise, $P \lor (\neg Q \lor Q)$ becomes '$P$ or a tautology', which is just a tautology. So: $P \lor (\neg Q \lor Q)$ is a tautology.

It is very useful to have an explicit tautology symbol. Logicians often use $\top$ for this.

So then you have:

$P \land (\neg Q \lor Q) \equiv P \land \top \equiv P$

and

$P \lor (\neg Q \lor Q) \equiv P \lor \top \equiv \top$

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  The ambiguosness was killing me.  I just needed to hear someone with more logic knowledge say this.  And I did not know about $T$.  Also, thank you Javi.

Comment: @greycatbird You're welcome!  And please understand that $\top$ is not the same as $T$: $\top$ is a statement, and $T$ is a truth-value. But $\top$ is a statement that is *always* true ... as tautologies are.